# Checking the value of json data

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

If I have json data which looks like this:

`{"d":1}`

How do I check if that `1` is a `1` or a `0`?

I have tried the following, but it goes straight to the `else`, even when I can see that the json data has a `1`.

```
success: function(data) {

    if (data[0]) {
        console.log("Results...");
    } else {
        console.log("No results...");
    }
```

the `data` contains `{"d":1}`

Comment: You forgot `javascript` in the tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  if (data["d"] == 1)
```

or simply

```
  if (data.d == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

data is a hash, so this should work:

```
if (data.d == 1) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be right if the JSON was actually an array:

```
[{"d":1}]
```

Since it's not, you can simply

```
if (data) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the "d" key to access the data associated with it, which is 1.

JSON is simply key-value pairs.

e.g.

```
if (data.d == 1) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
data.d == 1
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/avVRs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (data.d == 1){
   // do
}
```